# Google Calendar API change event creator

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

User `X` has some events and I want to change the owner of that event to user `Y`, both have same domain `@example.com`.

For this I found this [Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move#examples), the problem is that is not working (I get 404 on request). To make it work I have to add user `X` TO `Share with specific people` section, but I can't do that for every user and I am looking for solution to change ownership of an event.

The user `Y** is created by me via API so if there is something that I can do when I create that user will be also good.

Also I find something similar [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing#shared_event_properties), but not exactly what I need.

```
$client = $this->getClient(); // Here I have auth part with token
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$service->events->move(
    'primary', 
    $event->getId(),
   'newemail@gmail.com'
);
```

Comment: Please edit your question include [example] and describe what you mean by "the problem is that is not working".

Comment: I edited the question. I get 404 error and I also tried to change owner directly from  here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move , on Try this API section.

Comment: 404 means not found which probably means the event does not exist.  try doing an event list to ensure that the event id exists first.

Comment: I did some tests, I am sure that the events exists, that request worked only when  I added that user email on Share with specific people section.

Comment: and the user who you are currently logged in has write access to newemail@gmail.com calendar?

Comment: Not sure, how to check that. Second email is created by me via API. So if is some value that I should give it, I can, but I don't know what to set for that email in order to work.

Comment: The user who is currently logged in go have the user who owns newemail@gmail.com  go to Google calendar web UI and add share their primary calendar with them. I would check the calendar id because newemail@gmail.comis not a calendar id that was created via the api that's the primary calendar for the user new email  try [acl/list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list)

Comment: You cannot change the event creator. Is there a reason you need primary calendars here? Why can't you just create a new calendar that is not a primary, then make the other user a admin of that calendar, then move all the events?

Comment: At the moment ac/list seems to be a solution, but I still do some testing.. To duplicate this event is not a solution from various reasons.

Comment: Not duplicate, to move them to a calendar that is not a primary calendar